# HAPROXY configuration

Tags: configuration, haproxy

Can somebody please help me configure me haproxy:

On same server, multiple ports are used for different applications and I would like to create configuration for them:

So for example If I enter in my web browser *test.testdev.com* I would like tobe redirected to *192.168.24.121:8080*, and I if type *test.testdev.com/test-test/api* I would like to go to *192.168.24.121:10000/test-test/api*

**My configuration**:

```
acl testaaa_url hdr_dom(host) -i test.testdev.com
acl testbbb_url hdr_end(host) -i test.testdev.com/test-test

use_backend testaaa if_testaaa_url
user_backend testbbb if testbbb_url


backend testaaa
mode http
server testaaa 192.168.24.121:8080

backend testbbb 
mode http
server testbbb 192.168.24.121:10000
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ACLs do not compute. Neither there is a "user_backend" setting.

```
acl testaaa_url hdr_dom(host) -i test.testdev.com
acl testbbb_url hdr_end(host) -i test.testdev.com/test-test

use_backend testaaa if_testaaa_url
user_backend testbbb if testbbb_url

backend testaaa
 mode http
 server testaaa 192.168.24.121:8080

backend testbbb
 mode http
 server testbbb 192.168.24.121:10000
```

With your second ACL you are trying to match "test.testdev.com/test-test" at the end (therefore "hdr_end") of your host-header. But your host-header is only "test.testdev.com".

The ACL you are propably looking for could be:

```
acl testbbb_url path -i -m beg /test-test
```

To match any HTTP resource matching /test-test.

[ACLs can then be combined](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.3/configuration.html#7.2) with AND operators like this:

```
use_backend testbbb if testaaa_url testbbb_url
```

This way, both ACLs will have to be true for the condition to turn out true and forward to testbbb. (Meaning: the host-header will have to match "test.testdev.com" and the beginning of the HTTP resource will have to match "/test-test".

You would end up with a rough configuration like this:

```
acl testaaa_url hdr_dom(host) -i test.testdev.com
acl testbbb_url path -i -m beg /test-test

use_backend testbbb if testaaa_url testbbb_url
use_backend testaaa if testaaa_url

backend testaaa
 mode http
 server testaaa 192.168.24.121:8080

backend testbbb
 mode http
 server testbbb 192.168.24.121:10000
```

A good starting point is [the HAProxy introduction to ACLs](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/introduction-to-haproxy-acls/) and as follow up literature [the ACL section in the official documentation](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.3/configuration.html#7.1).